# Alternatives to pandas.query() when the column name is a Python keyword (import, sum, min etc)?

Tags: python, pandas, pandasql

The pandas documentation for query() states that

> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html
>
> Column names which are Python keywords (like “list”, “for”, “import”,
> etc) cannot be used.

This is why, in the toy example below, I cannot use pandas.query() to filter the columns called '`min`' nor '`sum`'

My question is: **what is an efficient and easy to read way to filter on multiple columns if I cannot use query() ? E.g. to run the pandas equivalent of a SQL statement like:**

```
select m.* from df m where (m.[min] > 0.5 and m.[min] < 0.9) or m.[sum] > 0.7
```

Using pandas syntax, this comes to mind:

```
out5 = df.loc[  ( (df['min'] > 0.5 )    & df['min'] < 0.9 ) | df['sum'] > 0.7  ]
```

which, well, works, but I find very hard to read, and much more obscure than in most other languages, from SQL to R.

**I also don't understand why the first condition [ min > 0.5 ] must be in brackets or else it won't work.**

I had thought of using the [pandasql](https://pypi.org/project/pandasql/) package, which loads dataframes into an in-memory SqlLite database, runs a query there, then exports back to pandas, but development stopped about 5 years ago, it's never reached version 1, and I am afraid that data types could be emssed up (eg SqlLite doesn't explicitly support dates or datetimes).

The toy example is this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','min','sum','col with space'] , data = np.random.rand(100,4))

# this works
out1 = df.query("a > 0.5" )

# this doesn't: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'float'
out2 = df.query(" min > 0.5 ")

# doesn't work:
# NumExprClobberingError: Variables in expression "(sum) > (0.5)" overlap with builtins: ('sum')
out3 = df.query(" sum > 0.5 ")

# this works
out4 = df.query(" `col with space` > 0.5 ")
```

Comment: they all work for me - pandas 1.2.1

Comment: `why the first condition [ min > 0.5 ] must be in bracket` operators precedence `&` goes before `>` and `0.5 & df['min']` isn't what you are looking for anyway.

Comment: I have pandas 1.2.1 and out2 and out3 don't work. Please note I have commented them out when copied the code

Comment: To be fair, you should avoid keywords for object names in Python, Pandas, SQL, and *any* other language.

Comment: In SQL it is extremely common to give columns names like 'sum', 'min', etc, and very easy to simply include them in square brackets. I also have many situations at work where, for reasons I won't go into here, some tables / charts / reports etc produced with Python MUST have names like import or min (there is categorically no way around that, not my choice, regardless of what my opinion may or may not be).

Comment: Actually, most SQL RBDMS have aggregate functions as reserved keywords. SQLite appears to be an [exception](http://www3.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html). See [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-keywords-appendix.html), [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-reserved-words-keywords.html#GUID-9BAA3A99-41B1-45CB-A91E-1E482BC1F927), ...

Comment: However, to second @RobRaymond, I cannot reproduce those errors in version 1.0.3 for Windows! Specifically, for `out2`, `min` indeed filters by 0.5 without TypeError. Same for `sum`. What is your OS environment?

Comment: That's very odd, I have tried with 2 Windows PCs and get the same error!

Answer (score 1):

I prefer duckdb:

```
import duckdb
df = duckdb.query('''/%SQL Code%/''').to_df()
```